# Как передать введенные данные в input на другую страницу в <p> с помощью свойств объекта Location

Tags: javascript

Нужно передать введенные данные в input на другую страницу (с помощью свойств объекта Location) в p

Страница 1

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function transfer(){
   var a = forma.text.value;
   location.href = "javascript6_21.html?+a";
   return false; 
}
</script>
<form id="forma" onsubmit="return transfer();">
<input type="text" name="text" value="Введите текст"/>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
```

Страница 2

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if(location.search)
{
var text = location.search.substring(1)
var tag = document.getElementById("tag");
var tt = tag.innerHTML + text
}
</script>
<p id="tag"></p>
</body>
```

Не пойму почему я остаюсь на первой странице. Почему значения из imput не считываются второй страницей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На Страница 1 надо указать `location.href = "javascript6_21.html?" + a;`

На Страница 2 надо скрипт расположить после тега.

```
<p id="tag"></p>
<script>
if (location.search) {
   var text = location.search.substring(1);
   document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

---

Другой вариант: на Страница 2 надо дождаться загрузку страницы.
Например, с помощью jquery так

```
<script>
$(function () {
  if (location.search) {
     var text = location.search.substring(1);
     document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = text;
  }
});    
</script>
<p id="tag"></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Stack! А какое значение имеет [  return false; ] ? Глупый вопрос, но хочется понять.

Comment: @JuliaParamonova _"А какое значение имеет [ return false; ] ?"_ -- в onsubmit передается false -- это отключает встроенную реакцию на событие. еще в обработчиках событий используют `event.stopPropagation();` и `event.cancelBubble();`

Comment: @ Stack Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Когда должна сработать функция `transfer`? В приведенном коде она не вызывается.

```
function transfer(){
  var a = document.getElementById("forma").text.value;
  location.href = "javascript6_21?"+a;
  return false; // !!!
}

<form id="forma" onsubmit="return transfer();">
...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Функция должна запускаться по нажатию кнопки отправить. Вы правы, я исправила. Но результата нет. Мне кажется ошибка в где-то здесь [location.href = "javascript6_21.html?+a";] Вторая страница считывает полностью выражение и не понимает адрес.