# Передача значение input на другую страничку

Tags: javascript, html, html5

У меня есть две странички takename.html и givename.html. На первой страничке есть input в котором пользователь пишет имя и фамилию (в один input) далее есть кнопка перехода на другую страничку (givename.html) где существует тег р . Суть задачи в том что с input нужно передать значение в тег р. Учитывая что это разные странички.

Comment: Вот решение схожей задачи https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487362/

Comment: Спасибо, щас гляну